# Mongo client not updating multiple records

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a **MongoDB** collection with many documents in the format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b64b79cf8b57c2face707d"),
    "my_id" : "MYMAINID00001",
    "position" : 4,
    "A" : 0,
    "B" : -2.17,
    "C" : -3.46
}
```

I am trying to update multiple records that match the `my_id` field using the command:

```
db.mycollection.update(
    {"my_id": "MYMAINID00001"}, 
    { $set: 
      {"my_id": "MYMAINID00001", 
       "start": 128, 
       "end": 255}
    },
    {
      $upsert: 1,
      $multi: 1
    }
)
```

However, this is simply creating  new document with 4 fields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b64b79cf8b57c2face707c"),
    "my_id" : "MYMAINID00001",
    "start" : 128,
    "end" : 255
}
```

And **not** updating currently existing records to include the `start` and `end` fields.

From looking at the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.update/), it looks like I am doing this correctly, but clearly something is wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas why this update command is not updating currently existing records?

I am still using Mongo 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. There is no `$upsert` or `$multi` operator

```
db.mycollection.update({ "my_id": "MYMAINID00001" }, 
    { "$set": { 
        "my_id": "MYMAINID00001", 
        "start": 128, 
        "end": 255
     }},
    { upsert: 1, multi: 1 }
)
```